# How do I send a cross-domain POST request via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain

How do I send a cross-domain POST request via JavaScript?

Notes - it shouldn't refresh the page, and I need to grab and parse the response afterwards.

Comment: I'd like to know a little about the use case that lets you try to do this. Could you please tell something about it?

Comment: Basically I'm working on a script that needs to send some text from an HTML file to another server for processing.

Comment: Can you set up a proxy that does this on the server-side and just gives your script the result? Or does it need to be 100% JavaScript?

Answer (score 406):

**Update:** Before continuing everyone should read and understand the [web.dev tutorial](https://web.dev/cross-origin-resource-sharing/) on CORS. It is easy to understand and very clear.

If you control the server being POSTed, simply leverage the "Cross-Origin Resource Sharing standard" by setting response headers on the server.  This answer is discussed in other answers in this thread, but not very clearly in my opinion.

In short here is how you accomplish the cross domain POST from from.com/1.html to to.com/postHere.php (using PHP as an example). Note: you only need to set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` for NON `OPTIONS` requests - this example always sets all headers for a smaller code snippet.

1. In postHere.php setup the following:

   ```
   switch ($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']) {
       case 'http://from.com': case 'https://from.com':
       header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
       header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
       header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
       header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
       break;
   }
   ```

   This allows your script to make cross domain POST, GET and OPTIONS.  This will become clear as you continue to read...
2. Setup your cross domain POST from JS (jQuery example):

   $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'https://to.com/postHere.php',
   crossDomain: true,
   data: '{"some":"json"}',
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
   var value = responseData.someKey;
   },
   error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
   alert('POST failed.');
   }
   });

When you do the POST in step 2, your browser will send a "OPTIONS" method to the server.  This is a "sniff" by the browser to see if the server is cool with you POSTing to it.  The server responds with an "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" telling the browser its OK to POST|GET|ORIGIN if request originated from "http://from.com" or "https://from.com".  Since the server is OK with it, the browser will make a 2nd request (this time a POST).  It is good practice to have your client set the content type it is sending - so you'll need to allow that as well.

MDN has a great write-up about [HTTP access control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control), that goes into detail of how the entire flow works. According to their docs, it should "work in browsers that support cross-site XMLHttpRequest". This is a bit misleading however, as I *THINK* only modern browsers allow cross domain POST.  I have only verified this works with safari,chrome,FF 3.6.

Keep in mind the following if you do this:

1. Your server will have to handle 2 requests per operation
2. You will have to think about the security implications. Be careful before doing something like 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'
3. This wont work on mobile browsers. In my experience they do not allow cross domain POST at all. I've tested android, iPad, iPhone
4. There is a pretty big bug in FF < 3.6 where if the server returns a non 400 response code AND there is a response body (validation errors for example), FF 3.6 wont get the response body. This is a huge pain in the ass, since you cant use good REST practices. See bug [here](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7868#comment:11) (its filed under jQuery, but my guess is its a FF bug - seems to be fixed in FF4).
5. Always return the headers above, not just on OPTION requests. FF needs it in the response from the POST.

Comment: Can it return html for example? I need to return html and something is not working...

Comment: Yea you should be able to. Never tried it tho. Your server returning 200? Also is your server returning the headers on the OPTIONs AND POST  requests?  I have updated my answer with more detail about this.  Make sure that your server is responding with the correct content-type header too (like text/html).  My recomendation is to use google chrome, right click page>inspect element. Click on network tab, and watch the POST and the response. Should give you info on what is going wrong.

Comment: I have tried this, but still get `400 Bad Request` on `OPTIONS` request. and in `firefox` the second request of `POST` is never made. :(

Comment: Is there a way to callout your local machine in your case statement above?  Or do you just have to use the * in this case for the allow origins.

Comment: @toddv You can add a domain in Access-Control-Allow-Origin, but downside is you cant add a list of domains.

Comment: For me, it didn't work until I also returned the response header `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-csrf-token`

Comment: @JellicleCat yes if your site is using csrf u'll need to add that

Comment: what if I don't own the server to which the post request is being made  ? Is there a work-around ?

Comment: I want to make a cross-Domain request from chrome-extension, so what will be my $_SERVER[HTTP_ORIGIN] in this case?

Comment: The behavior of firefox seems to have changed now? I don't get any option requests when I do this.

Comment: Does the server have to explicitly handle the preflight request or is it taken care of internally?

Comment: this was last edited 4 years ago - will this work on mobile browsers now?

Comment: hi @frankpinto did it work for mobile device or you used a different method?

Answer (score 125):

If you control the remote server, [you should probably use CORS, as described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7605119/); it's supported in IE8 and up, and all recent versions of FF, GC, and Safari. (But in IE8 and 9, CORS won't allow you to send cookies in the request.)

So, if you *don't* control the remote server, or if you have to support IE7, or if you need cookies and you have to support IE8/9, you'll probably want to use an iframe technique.

1. Create an iframe with a unique name. (iframes use a global namespace for the entire browser, so pick a name that no other website will use.)
2. Construct a form with hidden inputs, targeting the iframe.
3. Submit the form.

Here's sample code; I tested it on IE6, IE7, IE8, IE9, FF4, GC11, S5.

```
function crossDomainPost() {
  // Add the iframe with a unique name
  var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
  var uniqueString = "CHANGE_THIS_TO_SOME_UNIQUE_STRING";
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
  iframe.style.display = "none";
  iframe.contentWindow.name = uniqueString;

  // construct a form with hidden inputs, targeting the iframe
  var form = document.createElement("form");
  form.target = uniqueString;
  form.action = "http://INSERT_YOUR_URL_HERE";
  form.method = "POST";

  // repeat for each parameter
  var input = document.createElement("input");
  input.type = "hidden";
  input.name = "INSERT_YOUR_PARAMETER_NAME_HERE";
  input.value = "INSERT_YOUR_PARAMETER_VALUE_HERE";
  form.appendChild(input);

  document.body.appendChild(form);
  form.submit();
}
```

Beware! You won't be able to directly read the response of the POST, since the iframe exists on a separate domain. Frames aren't allowed to communicate with each other from different domains; this is the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

If you control the remote server but you can't use CORS (e.g. because you're on IE8/IE9 and you need to use cookies), there are ways to  work around the same-origin policy, for example by using [`window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage) and/or one of a number of libraries allowing you to send cross-domain cross-frame messages in older browsers:

- [Porthole](https://github.com/ternarylabs/porthole/)
- [XSSInterface](http://code.google.com/p/xssinterface/)
- [EasyXDM](http://easyxdm.net/)
- [jQuery PostMessage Plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/)

If you don't control the remote server, then you can't read the response of the POST, period. It would cause security problems otherwise.

Comment: You'll need to set form.target to something, or else the browser will navigate away from your site to the form action URL. Furthermore, the string needs to be unique; if there are other frames or windows using the same name, the form could post to that window instead of your iframe. But how unique does it have to be? Probably not very. The odds of clobbering are pretty small. *shrug*

Comment: @DanFabulich: That works for me in the sense that I'm able to call the service method, and the service returns the object in XML form (which I saw in Network tab of the Chrome Developer tools). But how would I get the result in my web page? Any way to set callback or something?

Comment: @Nawaz As I said in my answer, you'll have to do cross-domain cross-frame communication to get the result in your web page. It requires that you control the remote web server so you can modify its response to allow communication with your web page. (For one thing, the server will need to reply with HTML; if the server replies with raw XML, it can't do cross-frame communication.)

Comment: @DanFabulich: I didn't understand a single thing in your comment. These things are completely new to me; I'm not aware with the terminologies as well. Anyway, I used `XMLHttpRequest` and its working. But if you could explain your solution further, I would love to know that as well (maybe, your solution turns out to be better one for me).

Comment: +1 - this is the best solution I've found if you don't have access to the server

Comment: @DanFabulich, after submit form, how to read the response? Suppose I can control server. Can you give an example?

Comment: @jason Use Porthole, XSSInterface, EasyXDM, or jQuery PostMessage plugin.

Comment: @DanFabulich. After submit form, does server need return something for the iframe? How does the form page communicate with the data?

Comment: If its not possible to read the response, is it possible to send it to the server? For example that I would add a timeout and then get document.innerHTML and send it to my server?

Comment: @VojtechB No, that would be security hole.

Comment: @DanFabulich Thanks, this pointed me in the right direction, but there are several erros with the code, this code does not work. This article helped me http://scriptble.com/2012/02/15/how-to-create-and-write-to-an-iframe-without-jquery/

Comment: @DanFabulich Sentence in your answer `If you don't control the remote server, then you can't read the response of the POST, period`  is wrong. jcubic answer and code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38940932/how-to-invoke-form-post-to-other-domain-and-get-result-html-in-javascript contain solution for cross-domain POST result reading. You can consider improving answer by adding code for cross-domain response reading

Comment: @Andrus You can read result of the POST, but only if you control the server! See in that answer, it says "do X on the sender [client], do Y on the receiver [server]." If you don't control the receiver/server, you can't do Y, and so you can't read the result of the POST.

Answer (score 50):

1. Create an iFrame,
2. put a form in it with Hidden inputs,
3. set the form's action to the URL,
4. Add iframe to document
5. submit the form

Pseudocode

```
 var ifr = document.createElement('iframe');
 var frm = document.createElement('form');
 frm.setAttribute("action", "yoururl");
 frm.setAttribute("method", "post");

 // create hidden inputs, add them
 // not shown, but similar (create, setAttribute, appendChild)

 ifr.appendChild(frm);
 document.body.appendChild(ifr);
 frm.submit();
```

You probably want to style the iframe, to be hidden and absolutely positioned.  Not sure cross site posting will be allowed by the browser, but if so, this is how to do it.

Comment: Actually, this is slightly inaccurate, since ifr.appendChild(frm); will not work. the iframe is a reference to a window object, and the appendChild method doesn't exist for it. You'll need to grab the document node in the iframe first. This requires feature detection to work across browsers.

Comment: Thanks. Found these useful links regarding the matter: http://bindzus.wordpress.com/2007/12/24/adding-dynamic-contents-to-iframes/ 
http://developer.apple.com/internet/webcontent/iframe.html

Comment: Problem! The received response in the iframe lies at a different domain, so the main window has no access to it, neither does the iframe have access to the main window.

So this solution only seems good for doing the POST, but you can't parse the response afterward :(

Comment: Try setting an onload in the body tag of the response to a JavaScript function that calls a function in the parent with the response string.

Comment: This answer didn't work for me; I posted my own variation below.

Comment: jsonp should work to emulate "GET". How to transfer the authentication info to the iframe? I'd like to do authenticated posts to another domain.

Comment: Found a bug with code above in IE7. It seems doesn't allow to append child nodes created in main document object. Solved it by created form and input elements in next manner: var frm = ifr.contentWindow.document.createElement("form"); var input = ifr.contentWindow.document.createElement('input');

Comment: @LouFranco: That works for me in the sense that I'm able to call the service method, and the service returns the object in XML form (which I saw in Network tab of the Chrome Developer tools). But how would I get the result in my web page? Any way to set callback or something?

Comment: for access iframe of different domain, you need to add a child iframe to the iframe page and make sure the child iframe have the same domain as the parent domain. it will be something like this: 
<iframe id="x" src="http://www.aaa.com">
// I can read address of z!!!
  <iframe id="y" src="http://www.bbb.com">
     // I can set address of z!!!
      <iframe id="z" src="http://www.aaa.com?requestResult=done">

      </iframe>
  </iframe>
</iframe>

Answer (score 25):

Keep it simple:

1. ***cross-domain POST:***
   use `crossDomain: true,`
2. ***shouldn't refresh the page:*** 
   No, it will not refresh the page as the `success` or `error` async callback will be called when the server send back the response.

---

#### Example script:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://www.yoururl.com/",
        crossDomain: true,
        data: 'param1=value1&param2=value2',
        success: function (data) {
            // do something with server response data
        },
        error: function (err) {
            // handle your error logic here
        }
    });
```

Comment: `crossDomain: true` oddly has absolutely nothing to do with real cross-domain requests. If the request is cross-domain, jquery sets this to true automagically.

Answer (score 16):

If you have access to all servers involved, put the following in the header of the reply for the page being requested in the other domain:

PHP:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

For example, in Drupal's xmlrpc.php code you would do this:

```
function xmlrpc_server_output($xml) {
    $xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?>'."\n". $xml;
    header('Connection: close');
    header('Content-Length: '. strlen($xml));
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    header('Date: '. date('r'));
    // $xml = str_replace("\n", " ", $xml); 

    echo $xml;
    exit;
}
```

This probably creates a security problem, and you should make sure that you take the appropriate measures to verify the request.

Answer (score 9):

Check the `post_method` function in http://taiyolab.com/mbtweet/scripts/twitterapi_call.js - a good example for the iframe method described above.

Answer (score 6):

1. Create two hidden iframes (add "display: none;" to the css style). Make your second iframe point to something on your own domain.
2. Create a hidden form, set its method to "post" with target = your first iframe, and optionally set enctype to "multipart/form-data" (I'm thinking you want to do POST because you want to send multipart data like pictures?)
3. When ready, make the form submit() the POST.
4. If you can get the other domain to return javascript that will do Cross-Domain Communication With Iframes (http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes) then you are in luck, and you can capture the response as well.

Of course, if you want to use your server as a proxy, you can avoid all this. Simply submit the form to your own server, which will proxy the request to the other server (assuming the other server isn't set up to notice IP discrepancies), get the response, and return whatever you like.

Answer (score 6):

One more important thing to note!!!
In [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7605119/411671) above it's described how to use

```
$.ajax({
    type     : 'POST',
    dataType : 'json', 
    url      : 'another-remote-server',
    ...
});
```

JQuery 1.6 and lower has a bug with cross-domain XHR.
According to Firebug no requests except OPTIONS were sent. No POST. At all.

Spent 5 hours testing/tuning my code. Adding a lot of headers on the remote server (script). Without any effect.
But later, I've updated JQuery lib to 1.6.4, and everything works like a charm.

Comment: Whoopps, not in Opera 10.61. My final decision to do this was to use PHP proxy on my domain.

Comment: How did you use the PHP proxy? Can you guide me on that?

Comment: see the answers below, e.g. by Ivan Durst

Answer (score 5):

If you want to do this in ASP.net MVC environment with JQuery AJAX, follow these steps:
(this is a summary of the solution offered at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010457/cross-domain-posts-to-asp-net-mvc-app) thread)

Assume that "caller.com"(can be any website) needs to post to "server.com"(an ASP.net MVC application)

1. On the "server.com" app's Web.config add the following section:

   ```
     <httpProtocol>
         <customHeaders>
             <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
             <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
             <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST, GET, OPTIONS" />
         </customHeaders>
     </httpProtocol>
   ```
2. On the "server.com", we'll have the following action on the controller(called "Home") to which we will be posting:

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public JsonResult Save()
   {
       //Handle the post data...

       return Json(
           new
           {
               IsSuccess = true
           });
   }
   ```
3. Then from the "caller.com", post data from a form(with the html id "formId") to "server.com" as follow:

   ```
   $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "http://www.server.com/home/save",
           dataType: 'json',
           crossDomain: true,
           data: $(formId).serialize(),
           success: function (jsonResult) {
              //do what ever with the reply
           },
           error: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
               //handle error
           }
       });
   ```

Answer (score 4):

There is one more way (using html5 feature). You can use proxy iframe hosted on that other domain, you send message using postMessage to that iframe, then that iframe can do POST request (on same domain) and postMessage back with reposnse to the parent window.

parent on sender.com

```
var win = $('iframe')[0].contentWindow

function get(event) {
    if (event.origin === "http://reciver.com") {
        // event.data is response from POST
    }
}

if (window.addEventListener){
    addEventListener("message", get, false)
} else {
    attachEvent("onmessage", get)
}
win.postMessage(JSON.stringify({url: "URL", data: {}}),"http://reciver.com");
```

iframe on reciver.com

```
function listener(event) {
    if (event.origin === "http://sender.com") {
        var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
        $.post(data.url, data.data, function(reponse) {
            window.parent.postMessage(reponse, "*");
        });
    }
}
// don't know if we can use jQuery here
if (window.addEventListener){
    addEventListener("message", listener, false)
} else {
    attachEvent("onmessage", listener)
}
```

Comment: There is related question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38940932/how-to-invoke-form-post-to-other-domain-and-get-result-html-in-javascript . Is it possible to create some plugin or generic function based on your sample ?

Comment: @Andrus maybe something like this https://gist.github.com/jcubic/26f806800abae0db9a0dfccd88cf6f3c

Comment: This code requires modifying receiver page. How to read response if receiver pages cannot modified ?

Comment: @Andrus you can't you need to have access to recever.com iframe to send ajax requests there. Without iframe there will be no requests.

Answer (score 3):

High level.... You need to have a cname setup on your server so that other-serve.your-server.com points to other-server.com.

Your page dynamically creates an invisible iframe, which acts as your transport to other-server.com.  You then have to communicate via JS from your page to the other-server.com and have call backs that return the data back to your page.

Possible but requires coordination from your-server.com and other-server.com

Comment: Didn't even think of using a CNAME to redirect. Good call! I have yet to try this but I'm assuming that the CNAME will trick the browser into thinking it's interacting with the same site? I'm going to be using it to post to Amazon S3 so I'm hoping this works.

Comment: I dont see how this would solve anything. crossing to a different subdomain has the same problems as crossing to a different domain.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way is to use XMLHttpRequest (e.g. $.ajax(), $.post() in jQuery) with one of Cross-Origin Resource Sharing polyfills https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#wiki-CORS

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but I wanted to share my approach. I use cURL as a proxy, very easy and consistent. Create a php page called submit.php, and add the following code:

```
<?

function post($url, $data) {
$header = array("User-Agent: " . $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
return $response;
}

$url = "your cross domain request here";
$data = $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"];
echo(post($url, $data));
```

Then, in your js (jQuery here):

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'submit.php',
crossDomain: true,
data: '{"some":"json"}',
dataType: 'json',
success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    var value = responseData.someKey;
},
error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert('POST failed.');
}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but some new technology might help someone out.

If you have administrative access to the other server then you can use the opensource Forge project to accomplish your cross-domain POST. Forge provides a cross-domain JavaScript XmlHttpRequest wrapper that takes advantage of Flash's raw socket API. The POST can even be done over TLS.

The reason you need administrative access to the server you are POSTing to is because you must provide a cross-domain policy that permits access from your domain.

http://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge

Answer (score 1):

Should be possible with a YQL custom table + JS XHR, take a look at:
http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/index.html

I use it to do some client side (js) html scraping, works fine 
(I have a full audio player, with search on internet/playlists/lyrics/last fm informations, all client js + YQL)

Answer (score 1):

CORS is for you.
CORS is "Cross Origin Resource Sharing", is a way to send cross domain request.Now the XMLHttpRequest2 and Fetch API both support CORS, and it can send both POST and GET request

But it has its limits.Server need to specific claim the **Access-Control-Allow-Origin**, and it can not be set to '*'.

And if you want any origin can send request to you, you need JSONP (also need to set **Access-Control-Allow-Origin**, but can be '*')

For lots of request way if you don't know how to choice, I think you need a full functional component to do that.Let me introduce a simple component **https://github.com/Joker-Jelly/catta**

---

If you are using modern browser (> IE9, Chrome, FF, Edge, etc.), Very Recommend you to use a simple but beauty component **https://github.com/Joker-Jelly/catta**.It have no dependence, Less than 3KB, and it support Fetch, AJAX and JSONP with same deadly sample syntax and options.

```
catta('./data/simple.json').then(function (res) {
  console.log(res);
});
```

It also it support all the way to import to your project, like ES6 module, CommonJS and even `<script>` in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the cross domain server and don't want to make any code changes on server side, you can use a library called - 'xdomain'.

How it works:

Step 1:
server 1: include the xdomain library and configure the cross domain as a slave:

```
<script src="js/xdomain.min.js" slave="https://crossdomain_server/proxy.html"></script>
```

Step 2:
on cross domain server, create a proxy.html file and include server 1 as a master:

```
proxy.html:
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<script src="js/xdomain.min.js"></script>
<script>
  xdomain.masters({
    "https://server1" : '*'
  });
</script>
```

Step 3:

Now, you can make an AJAX call to the proxy.html as endpoint from server1. This is bypass the CORS request. The library internally uses iframe solution which works with Credentials and all possible methods: GET, POST etc.

Query ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'https://crossdomain_server/proxy.html',
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(_data),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    })
    .done(_success)
    .fail(_failed)
```